# rails How to properly rollback certain migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

In my blog project, I used paperclip to manage the pictures. Now I'd like to switch to carrierwave, and want to make my project as if paperclip was never there.

First of, this is what the project looks like:
Every blogpost has many pictures, and every picture has one image.
So I generated a model for the gallery

```
rails g model pictures
```

this creates the migration `create_pictures.rb`
and the `picture` model. 
Then I added the image attribute to the picture model

```
rails g paperclip picture image
```

this created the migration `AddAttachementImageToPictures.rb`
Then I created the migration `AddPostIdToPictures`

Now I want to make a migration that gets rid of all this stuff. 2 of the 3 migrations are about adding attributes to the `pictures` table. So I wonder if I could just remove the `pictures` table and the `picture` model?

```
rails g migration RemovePictures
rails d model Picture
```

Or do I need to remove the attributes first, and then the whole table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are doing right thing. You should remove `pictures` table and then `Picture` model.

You don't need to remove each single column separately if you don't need that table. Or if you are planing to use same model for carrierwave as well then you can just remove attribute for paperclip and create new one for carrierwave.

This [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) will help you in migration changes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can remove the two lines mentioned and that should be enough.

In case you have already uploaded some images and want to have the same models with just a change of gem. Have a look here [Migrate from paperclip to carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-migrate-from-paperclip-to-carrierwave-(example-thor-task))

You can also read along, [Carrierwave migration](http://bessey.io/blog/2013/04/07/migrating-from-paperclip-to-carrierwave/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to rollback to specific version use:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547
```